# How to get URL of uploaded file from Amazon S3 Cloud Service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

4th post here with probably a stupid question. I uploaded photos to my AWS S3 acct and am trying to figure out if there is an easy way to get the urls of the files in one swoop?

Comment: which gem are you using?

Comment: Yeah need more information. Exactly how are you uploading files ? Do you want the urls of all files that are there or the files you have just uploaded ?

Comment: Why not just store the url in a database when uploading? The nomenclature goes "https://[BUCKET].s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/file". However, if they're private you need to generate a secure URL which is a different story.

Comment: @koshlendra the gems for this specifically were  'aws-sdk', '~> 2.0'
gem 'aws-sdk-rails' .

Comment: @xyious Sorry for not supplying enough information. I was uploading the files from my local system to the AWS S3 site. I wanted each individual url. I am making a yearbook and these are pictures from the bootcamp.

Comment: @hdezela I was just going into the s3 upload process blindly bc I saw there was a way to transfer the data to heroku. I was in school at the time and didn't take the time to read up on it. I thought that it was a database and I could just download the urls easily.

Comment: @LaFrish 'aws-sdk-rails' only Integrates AWS services with your Rails application but for the uploading which gem are you using like carrierwave ?